# How to hide the keyboard while using TableView in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

In my application I have textfield and while inserting any values in it it is displaying according values to the tableview as the no. of rows.

I want that when I scroll on the Tableview with having so many filled rows ,the keyboard must be hidden at the time of scrolling.

I have search on the net,but unable to find out the solution.

please give any solution with code snippet or valuable link or any solution.

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your table controller, add this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `[myTextField resignFirstResponder]` puts the keyboard modal view away. Depending on how you have set up handling scrolling, this should be enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just write this code where you want to hide the keyboard. With this code there is no need to do resignFirstResponder.

[self.view endEditing:YES];

Njoy.. :)